# How do I include the main navigation block twice?

Tags: 8, blocks

How can I put one block, for example the main navigation block, in two different regions. In Drupal 7 this was possible through the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, but as this module won't be ported to Drupal 8, I guess there is an other method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is present out of the box in Drupal 8. You can actually place the same block multiple times in different regions.

For adding a block multiple times:

1. Go to Admin -> Structure -> Block layout (/admin/structure/block).
2. Click on "Place block" button besides the region name.
3. Select any block you wish to add to that region.

Follow the same steps to add block to a different region.

Comment: Great improvement! Don't know, why I didn't saw this!